# Assistance in getting all text from paragraph that contains certain words

Tags: c#, interop

I am looking for assistance with my code.  Right now I can get all the text that have a certain style but I am looking to get all the paragraphs that contain certain words such as "The builder shall" or "The builder will.

I've have been successful in getting all the header text using the code below but I can't figure out how to get the paragraphs that contain the words "the builder will" or "the builder shall"

```
Document doc1 = new Document();

doc1.LoadFromFile(@"C:................DocumentToExtractFrom.docx");

// Initialzie StringBuilder Instance
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (Section section in doc1.Sections)
{
   foreach (Paragraph paragraph in section.Paragraphs)             
   {                  
      if ((paragraph.StyleName == "Heading2") || (paragraph.StyleName == "Heading3"))               
      {
         sb.AppendLine(" - "+ paragraph.Text+";");
      }
   }
}

string path = @"C:...................\DocumentToExtractTo.txt";

File.WriteAllText(path, sb.ToString());
```

I am looking for a final document that has all the extracted paragraphs in it.  As I said, I can get the document with the headings but can't seem to find the correct code to get the paragraphs that contain the words as above.

Comment: You can access yourParagraph.Range.Text property that should return you the text in the paragraph. So you can add conditions to your if statements to check for the specific words/sentences you are looking for.

Comment: Omar, any way you can provide me with an example that will support my code.  I am at a loss where to put the Paragraph.Range.Text into the code, can you show me where I would put that.  I appreciate any help, I'm new to this and it has been driving me absolutely crazy.  I know the solution is simple, I just can't seem to get there.  Thanks in advance. Ed

Comment: Sorry I just noticed your comment. Why don't you extend your If statement to add another condition like : 
if ((paragraph.StyleName == "Heading2") || (paragraph.StyleName == "Heading3" &&(paragraph.Text.Contains("The Builder Shall")||paragraph.Text.Contains("The builder will"))))?